# How to implement Filtering and Sorting in UI5 Table (sap.m.Table)

Tags: sapui5

I have implemented one table with JSONModel. Now I would like to add 2 buttons in toolbar for Sorting and filtering. How Can I achieve that? I have created the view in JS , so code help in JS is appreciated.

Please find below mentioned code for reference and please help me to implement sorting and filtering buttons.

```js
sap.ui.jsview("com.sap.view.View1", {

    /** Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
     * In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
     * @memberOf controller.View1
     */
    getControllerName: function() {
        return "com.sap.controller.View1";
    },

    /** Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
     * Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away.
     * @memberOf controller.View1
     */
    createContent: function(oController) {

        var oColumn1 = new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "ID"})}
        );
        var oColumn2 = new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "First Name"})}
        );
        var oColumn3 = new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Label({text: "Last Name"})}
        );
        var oColumn4 = new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "Email"})}
        );
        var oColumn5 = new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({text: "City"})}
        );

        var oTable = new sap.m.Table("idTabel",{
                headerToolbar: new sap.m.Toolbar({
            content: [
            /*  new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "Sales Order List"
                }), new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer({}),*/

                new sap.m.Button("idPersonalizationButton", {
                    icon: "sap-icon://action-settings"
                }),
                    new sap.m.Button("idFSG", {
                    icon: "sap-icon://filter"
                })

            ]
        }),
            headerText: "Employee",
            columns:[oColumn1,oColumn2,oColumn3,oColumn4,oColumn5],
            mode: sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectMaster,
            selectionChange:[oController.onSelect, oController]

        });


        var oTemp = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [new sap.m.Text({text: "{id}"}),
                   new sap.m.Text({text: "{first_name}"}),
                   new sap.m.Text({text: "{last_name}"}),
                   new sap.m.Text({text: "{email}"}),
                   new sap.m.Text({text: "{city}"})]


        });

        oTable.bindItems({
            path: "/details",
            template: oTemp
        });

       // oTable.setModel(oModel);

        return new sap.m.Page({
        title: "Simple Table",
        content: [oTable
        ]
    });
    }

});
```

Comment: For dynamic filtering checkout: the FacetFilter (has a nice ui) https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FacetFilter.html#constructor

Example from SAP: 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.FacetFilterSimple/preview


For Sorting get the table byId: sap.ui.getCore().byId("idTable").sort("<ColumnName>", SortOrder.Ascending);

If SortOrder.Ascending does not work you can also use a string "ascending"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
My conclusion:

> If you want to use sap.m.Table the only way is to set the property useTablePersonalisation: "true"
>   Or you use sap.ui.Table which is easier to manipulate, but it's ugly and old.